# How can I submit an HTML form written in javascript without button?

Tags: javascript, html

This is what I have tried so far, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
      var myJSON = JSON.stringify(distMatrix);

      var testform = `<form id="jsform" action="test.php" >
        <input type="hidden" name="array" value="${myJSON}"> /
      </form>`

      var printdata = document.getElementById('jsform');
      document.write(printdata);
      document.getElementById('jsform').submit();
```

Comment: Why are you trying to create a form instead of just sending the HTTP request?

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Comment: what is distMatrix? undefined variable? array?

Comment: its an array. does it matter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send POST data using XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/send-post-data-using-xmlhttprequest)

Comment: yes, because the array syntax comes into play when using stringify, and it has to be formatted for submitting

Comment: @Clabis check this answer if you just need to send some date from your js https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/send-post-data-using-xmlhttprequest#9713078

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to submit your form before it is actually created. 
First do document write and then submit.

**UPD:** ok, here we go.

1. Create form by simply putting it to html part of your file.
2. Set the required data into input via JS
3. submit the form

```js
var distMatrix = [[1,2],[2,2]];

// save the value into input
var input = document.getElementById('dist_matrix_json');
input.value = JSON.stringify(distMatrix);

// submit the form
document.getElementById('jsform').submit();
```

```html
<form id="jsform" action="test.php" >
    <input type="hidden" id="dist_matrix_json" name="array" value=""> /
</form>
```

Comment: it looks like they just are passing a json object, which would be just a simple XMLHttpRequest() routine and no html.

Comment: @drtechno you're right and that is far not the only issue of the example. yet, to answer the question asked we only need to put submitting line at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Sending a json object can be as simple as this javascript :

```
 <script>
 var myObj = { "name":"John", "age":31, "city":"New York" };
 var myJSON = JSON.stringify(myObj);
 window.location = "demo_json.php?x=" + myJSON;
 </script>
```

That was for the GET method.

if you need post or put methods:

```
    <div>
      <form id="myForm" action="page.php" method="post">
          <p id="demo"></p>
      </form>
    </div>

    <script>
     var myObj, x;
     myObj = {"name":"John", "age":30, "car":null};
     for (x in myObj) {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += '<input type="text" name="'+x+'" value="'+myObj[x]+'"><br>';
      }
      document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
     </script>
```